# Navigation in Jetpack Compose - Fragments/ViewModels

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation, navigation-compose

So I'm checking this official Compose tutorial https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose

There is Jetpack Compose Navigation

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation

So basically in that sample there is just one activity, no fragments and composables (implements 3 screens) are used for navigation graph instead of fragments

This sample is also really bad because it doesn't have ViewModels at all...

So basically how would a real app would look right now?

A single Activity with a single ViewModel and a lot of screens made in composables which use the same ViewModel (which of course is really bad)? Or I guess we should add a separate ViewModel inside of each start composable function of a specific screen instead of Activity (which could have only one single ViewModel - one lifecycle)

[image]

So basically we don't need fragments any more nowadays?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question. But here are a few pointers - no we don't need fragments any more. ViewModel's live in the BackStackEntry and are garbage collected when they go out of scope. Also in compose there is a new idea in the community where you don't need viewmodels any more - this is possible as Compose funciton are configuration change aware.

Comment: @clamentjohn how I start/stop camera in compose screen then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70391108/lifecycle-of-android-components-resources-api-such-as-camera-api-in-single-jet?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You can use a [LocalLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalLifecycleOwner()) to get the current lifecycle. This [example](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pengj/17e172110dee1bd1dc074d87b3eb90f3/raw/fce0e50af023b775baa9968e432a85273431af88/SimpleCameraPreview.kt) seem to have an example solution

Comment: check out official [compose-samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples), it has some projects with view models and navigation