# Lifecycle of Android components/resources/API (such as Camera API) in single Jetpack Compose screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Using Jetpack Compose we have only one `Activity` and no `Fragments` anymore - [Navigation in Jetpack Compose - Fragments/ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390848/navigation-in-jetpack-compose-fragments-viewmodels)

So basically each screen is just a composable function

As I understand we can't use `onStart/onPause/onResume/onStop` methods of `Activity` to control some components of composable screen anymore because it basically the lifecycle for all screens and we don't have `Fragments` anymore to have similar lifecycle methods for each screen anymore

For example how to implement a custom photo capture screen using Camera API in compose screen right now? Where should we start and stop a camera (control its lifecycle)? It should be done in `ViewModel` (`init` for to start the camera and `onCleared` to stop the camera) which belongs to a composable function of a specific screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are Android activities handled with Jetpack Compose and Compose Navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962458/how-are-android-activities-handled-with-jetpack-compose-and-compose-navigation)